# Plcc & breadboards

Tags: prototyping

I've selected a MCU in a PLCC packing and is desperate need of tips how to use it when prototyping on a breadboard. There is a DIP version of the MCU but it has some limitation due to a lower pin count, which forces me to use the PLCC packaging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a PLCC to DIP adapter.

Searching google for "PLCC DIP adapter" threw up a few. This kind of thing:

http://www.order-bulk.com/images/dip40plcc44.jpg

Comment: Question, why do it convert the 44 pin plcc to a 40 pin dip ?

Comment: Perhaps there are several power and ground pins

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to solder wires in the pins of the chip.
[image]